# Python - Iterating over a list of lists and printing the contents out

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

I have a list of lists that contains different characters and values that are assigned to them. So my list is something like:

```
player_list = [['Bruce Wayne', 5, 5, 0, 0, 100, 15], ['Jessica Jones', 12, 0, 6, 6, 10, 6], ['Johnny Rose', 6, 2, 0, 4, 20, 10], ['Gina Linetti', 7, 4, 0, 3, 300, 15], ['Buster Bluth', 3, 0, 2, 1, 50, 1]]
```

I want to be able to make a loop that goes through each player and prints their name and all of their stats. I have tried to make many loops but they either print the stats from different players or it doesn't print the whole list. The latest one that I have tried prints the first name and then the first 4 numbers and then stops.

```
index = 0
index1 = 0
while index < len(player_list):
    print(player_list[index1][index])
    index = index + 1
index1 += 1
```

The output to this code prints:

```
Bruce Wayne
5
5
0
0
```

And that's it. I need it to go though the whole thing and print them out like this:

```
Bruce Wayne      5  5  0  0  100  15
Jessica Jones    12  0  6  6  10  6
Johnny Rose      6  2  0  4  20  10
Gina Linetti     7  4  0  3  300  15
Buster Bluth     3  0  2  1  50  1
```

Edit: I need to be able to format the characters and their scores to this template:

```
============================================================
-                      Player Summary                      -
============================================================
-                              P  W  L  D   Chips   Score  -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to align the columns, then use f-strings with a width specifier:

```
for name, *stats in player_list:
    print(f"{name:15}", *(f"{stat:4}" for stat in stats))
```

Output:

```
Bruce Wayne        5    5    0    0  100   15
Jessica Jones     12    0    6    6   10    6
Johnny Rose        6    2    0    4   20   10
Gina Linetti       7    4    0    3  300   15
Buster Bluth       3    0    2    1   50    1
```

#### After edit, using template

For getting the specific layout you added to your question, do this:

```
print("""============================================================
-                      Player Summary                      -
============================================================
-                              P  W  L  D   Chips   Score  -""")

for name, p, w, l, d, chips, score in player_list:
    print(f"- {name:27} {p:2} {w:2} {l:2} {d:2} {chips:7} {score:7}  -")
print("============================================================")
```

Output:

```
============================================================
-                      Player Summary                      -
============================================================
-                              P  W  L  D   Chips   Score  -
- Bruce Wayne                  5  5  0  0     100      15  -
- Jessica Jones               12  0  6  6      10       6  -
- Johnny Rose                  6  2  0  4      20      10  -
- Gina Linetti                 7  4  0  3     300      15  -
- Buster Bluth                 3  0  2  1      50       1  -
============================================================
```

Comment: Sorry didn't refresh the page after you edited that has solved it. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a way that I can sort this list into the different categories so that people with more chips are on the top?

Comment: Sure, check out `sort` or `sorted`, it has an argument with which you can control sort order. Look around, there are many Q&A on the topic. If you cannot make it work, ask a new question about it, showing your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the player_list and unpack each element thus:

```
player_list = [['Bruce Wayne', 5, 5, 0, 0, 100, 15], ['Jessica Jones', 12, 0, 6, 6, 10, 6], ['Johnny Rose', 6, 2, 0, 4, 20, 10], ['Gina Linetti', 7, 4, 0, 3, 300, 15], ['Buster Bluth', 3, 0, 2, 1, 50, 1]]

for player in player_list:
    print(*player)
```

**Output:**

```
Bruce Wayne 5 5 0 0 100 15
Jessica Jones 12 0 6 6 10 6
Johnny Rose 6 2 0 4 20 10
Gina Linetti 7 4 0 3 300 15
Buster Bluth 3 0 2 1 50 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your list to a dictionary then iterate through it and print each pair of key, values as follows :

```
res = dict()
res = {tuple(sub[:1]): tuple(sub[1:]) for sub in player_list}

all_players = player_list
for k,v in res.items():
    print(k[0], v)

>>>
Bruce Wayne (5, 5, 0, 0, 100, 15)
Jessica Jones (12, 0, 6, 6, 10, 6)
Johnny Rose (6, 2, 0, 4, 20, 10)
Gina Linetti (7, 4, 0, 3, 300, 15)
Buster Bluth (3, 0, 2, 1, 50, 1)
```